# Semantic UI React useState() messes with input range slider?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, semantic-ui

I'm trying to create a input slider with a text bubble next to it that displays what the current value is. I'm using the useState() function to track the position and update it in the bubble. messageDays is the value, setMessageDays() is the function.

The slider works fine on its own, but when I try to handle a change in the slider's position, using the event.target.value as input for setMessageDays(), the input slider suddenly refuses to move fluidly. Sometimes it stutters a step, other times it doesn't move at all. The bubble *does* update, but only when you click on a specific location on the slider for it to jump to.

My debugging seems to indicate that it doesn't matter *which* useState function reads it (as can be seen with the setMess2() function in the code below, a function that doesn't connect to the slider or Label), as it'll stop moving fluidly regardless.

The other potential culprit could be the formatting functions - I used a slider without any of the prettiness before and both the slider and bubble updated worked to standard.

In the current form (with everything but the formatting function commented out) the slider moves and colors correctly, but the text bubble doesn't update (not that I'd expect it to, since the value isn't updating).

```
const RedoneSlider = () => {

  const rangeRef = useRef(null);
  const linearGradientColor="#6495ED";
  const rangeBackgroundColor="#d7dcdf";
  const sliderThumbColor="#6393ed";

  const rangedSliderAttributes = {
    '&::-webkit-slider-thumb': {
        backgroundColor: sliderThumbColor,
        boxShadow: `0 0 0 3px #fff, 0 0 0 6px ${sliderThumbColor}`
    },
    '&::-moz-range-thumb': {
        backgroundColor: sliderThumbColor,
        boxShadow: `0 0 0 3px #fff, 0 0 0 6px ${sliderThumbColor}`
    },
  }

  const calculatePercentage = (value, min, max) => {
    return ((value - min) / (max - min)) * 100 + '%';
  }

  const rangeLinearGradient = (value, min, max) => {
    const percentage = calculatePercentage(value, min, max);
    const newBackgroundStyle = `linear-gradient(90deg, ${linearGradientColor} 0% ${percentage}, ${rangeBackgroundColor} ${percentage} 100%)`;
    rangeRef.current.style.background = newBackgroundStyle;
  }

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    //setMessageDays(e.target.value);
    //setMess2(e.target.value);
    rangeLinearGradient(e.target.value, 1, 14);
    //setMess2(e.target.value);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <input ref={rangeRef} className={`range-slider ${rangedSliderAttributes}`} type="range" min={1} max={14} step={1} setDefaultValue={messageDays} onChange={handleChange} ></input>
      <Label size='large' pointing='left' >{messageDays}</Label>
    </div>);
}
```